# Join two Pandas dataframes with new column containing combined matching results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this has been answered already, but I wasn't able to find a similar post.

I've got two Pandas dataframes that I'd like to merge. Dataframe1 contains data which has failed validation. Dataframe2 contains the detail for each row where the errors have occurred (ErrorColumn).

As you can see in Dataframe2, there can be multiple errors for a single row. I need to consolidate the errors, then append them as a new column (ErrorColumn) in Dataframe1.

Example below

Dataframe 1:

| ErrorRow | MaterialID | Description | UnitCost | Quantity | Critical | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | nan | Part 1 | nan | 100 | false | West |
| 4 | nan | Part 2 | 12 | nan | true | East |
| 7 | 56779 | Part 3 | 25 | nan | false | West |

Dataframe 2:

| ErrorRow | ErrorColumn |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | MaterialID |
| 3 | UnitCost |
| 4 | MaterialID |
| 4 | Quantity |
| 7 | Quantity |

Result:

| ErrorRow | MaterialID | Description | UnitCost | Quantity | Critical | Location | ErrorColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | nan | Part 1 | nan | 100 | false | West | MaterialID, UnitCost |
| 4 | nan | Part 2 | 12 | nan | true | East | MaterialID, Quantity |
| 7 | 56779 | Part 3 | 25 | nan | false | West | Quantity |

Any assistance is appreciated. I'm new to Python, there's likely a simple solution that I have yet to find/learn.

Comment: Could you reformat the data frames in your question so they render as tables?

Comment: I just noticed that. It renders correctly in edit mode. Let me find the issue and correct it.

Comment: Formatting has been fixed

Comment: One small question. Is 'ErrorRow' only to be used within your script? A globally unique identifier would be useful for maintaining a data trail. 


abokey answers your question.

Comment: A set would be ideal, since the values in ErrorRow will be later used. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html?highlight=groupby%20agg#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg) :

```
out = df1.merge(df2.groupby("ErrorRow", as_index=False).agg(", ".join), on="ErrorRow")
#or if set needed, use GroupBy.agg(set)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out.to_string())
​
   ErrorRow  MaterialID Description  UnitCost  Quantity  Critical Location           ErrorColumn
0         3         NaN      Part 1       NaN     100.0     False     West  MaterialID, UnitCost
1         4         NaN      Part 2      12.0       NaN      True     East  MaterialID, Quantity
2         7     56779.0      Part 3      25.0       NaN     False     West              Quantity
```

Comment: If further processing of 'ErrorColumn' is needed a set might be easier to work with than a concatenated string.

Comment: True but I just tried to give the OP the expected output he's looking for.

Comment: Understood. Just looking past the immediate ask. (i.e. See comment above re GUIDs)

Comment: You case use `.agg(set)` if set is needed.

Comment: Works beautifully